# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf') in firebase v9 {modular}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**I changed my code from firebase v8 to v9, I am able to write the data in db but couldn't get and map it.**

My data is stored in db like this : users >> user.uid >> orders >> paymentIntent.id,

each doc saved has amount, basket data, created

Please check mentioned screenshot.

**Previous code:**

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      db.collection("users")
        .doc(user?.uid)
        .collection("orders")
        .orderBy("created", "desc")
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
          // console.log(snapshot);
          setOrders(
            snapshot.docs.map((doc, i) => ({
              key: { i },
              id: doc.id,
              data: doc.data(),
            }))
          );
        });
    } else {
      setOrders([]);
    }
  }, [user]);
```

My data is stored in db like this : users >> user.uid >> orders >> paymentIntent.id,

each doc saved has amount, basket data, created

Please check mentioned screenshot.

**This is firestore inserted data**

[firestore added data in db, screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgJfv.png)

**This is my new code**

```
import { collection, doc, getDoc, getDocs, onSnapshot, orderBy, query } from 'firebase/firestore';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { db } from './firebase';
import './Orders.css'
import { useStateValue } from './StateProvider';
import Order from './Order';

function Orders() {
  const [{ basket, user}, dispatch] = useStateValue();
  const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);


useEffect(() => {
  const getDocs = async () => {
    try {
      const collRef = await getDocs(collection(db, "users", user?.id, "orders"));
      // const collRef = doc(db, "users", user?.id, "orders"));
      // const collRef = collection(db, "users", user?.id, "orders"));

      const orderedRef = query(collRef, orderBy("created", "desc"));
      const docSnap = onSnapshot(orderedRef, (snapshot) => {
        snapshot.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          data: doc.data(),
        }));
        setOrders(docSnap);
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    }
  };
  getDocs();
}, [user]);

  return (
    <div className="orders">
      <h3>Your Orders</h3>
      <div className="orders__order">
        {orders?.map((order, i) => (
          <Order key={i} order={order} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Orders;
```

[Console, screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9lj3.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess it that `user` doesn't have a value, so `user?.id` becomes `undefined`. You'll want to still check whether `user` has a value inside the second snippet too.

For example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const getDocs = async (user: User) => {
    try {
      const collRef = await getDocs(collection(db, "users", user.id, "orders"));

      ...
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.message);
    }
  };
  if (user) {
    getDocs(user!);
  }
}, [user]);
```

Comment: Thank you @Frank van Puffelen for replying. Yes Sir I tried to log user and user.id , which are undefined.

Comment: @FaisalNazir I'm not sure why you unaccepted my answer. Was the user not `null` after all?

Comment: Sir, your answer is correct, you only gave me hint to fix my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (user) {
    try {
            const collRef = collection(db, "users", user?.uid, "orders");
            const orderedRef = query(collRef, orderBy("created", "desc"));
            const docSnap = onSnapshot(orderedRef, (querySnapshot) => {
              const orderArray = [];
              querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                orderArray.push({
                  id: doc.id,
                  data: doc.data()
                })
              })
              setOrders(orderArray);
             });
          } catch (err) {
            console.log(err.message);
          } 
  } else {
    console.log("not found");
    setOrders([]);
  }
}, [user]);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).