# Angular. How can I change quantity of item in firestore database?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase

When I add an item to the cart and want to change the quantity - the quantity does not change in the firestore database and the console displays this error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')`. I suspect that some functions are written incorrectly, because they previously were written under `json-server`

This is a `products.service.ts`

```
  postProductToBasket(product: IProducts) {
    const basketRef = collection(this.firestore, 'basket')
    return addDoc(basketRef, product)
  }

  updateProductToBasket(product: IProducts): Observable<any> {
    const ref = doc(this.firestore, 'products', product.uid)
    return from(updateDoc(ref, {...product}))
  }

  deleteProductFromBasket(product: IProducts) {
    const productDocRef = doc(this.firestore, `products/${product.id}`)
    return deleteDoc(productDocRef)
  }
```

This is some functions responsible for posting and updating items from `products.component.ts`

```
  addToBasket(product: IProducts) {
    product.quantity = 1
    let findItem;

    if (this.basket.length > 0) {
      findItem = this.basket.find((item) => item.id === product.id)
      if (findItem) {
        this.updateToBasket(findItem)
      } else {
        this.postToBasket(product)
      }
    } else {
      this.postToBasket(product)
    }
    
  }

  postToBasket(product: IProducts) {
    this.ProductsService.postProductToBasket(product)
  }

  updateToBasket(product: IProducts) {
    product.quantity += 1;
    this.ProductsService.updateProductToBasket(product).subscribe()
  }
```

These are functions responsible for increasing and decreasing the number of goods from `basket.component.ts`

```
  minusItemFromBasket(item: any) {
    if(item.quantity === 1) {
      this.ProductsService.deleteProductFromBasket(item.id)
        let idx = this.basket.findIndex((data) => data.id === item.id)
        this.basket.splice(idx, 1)
        this.total = 0
      
    } else {
      item.quantity -= 1;
      this.ProductsService.updateProductToBasket(item).subscribe((data) => {
        this.basket.forEach(item => {
          this.total -= item.price
        })
      })
    }

  }

  plusItemFromBasket(item: IProducts) {
    item.quantity += 1;
    this.ProductsService.updateProductToBasket(item).subscribe((data) => {
      this.basket.forEach(item => {
        this.total += item.price
      })
    });
  }
```

Comment: Can you rule out [this question with same error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73859212/4711754)? i.e. log out `product.uid` in `updateProductToBasket` to make sure this is defined.

Comment: @AndrewAllen Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Сan you write it down your answer?

Comment: It might not be the answer but that question has the same error. Before the line `const ref =  doc(this.firestore, 'products', product.uid)` put `console.log(product.uid)` to check if `product.uid` is defined.

Comment: @AndrewAllen Nope, it's `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments you're getting error from `product.uid` being undefined.

```
  updateProductToBasket(product: IProducts): Observable<any> {

    // product.uid MUST be defined or error will occur on following:
    const ref = doc(this.firestore, 'products', product.uid) 
    return from(updateDoc(ref, {...product}))
  }
```

The cause of this error is likely due to assuming id's are defined for items in the basket array and that product.uid is defined. The following runnable code demostrates the issue

```js
basket = [{ number: 1 }, { number: 2 }];
product = {
   name: "Pepperoni pizza"
};

findItem = this.basket.find((item) => item.id === product.id)
console.log(findItem)
// result: { number: 1 }

if(findItem) {
    console.log("findItem is truthy but id =", findItem.id)
    // this is where updateProductToBasket is called in your code.
}
```

Note also `product.uid` and `product.id` is being called.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I fixed it and now, when I adding the product to the cart, the product data is displayed in the console. But I still get an error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')` when I try to increase or decrease the quantity of items in the cart and the value of the quantity data is not updated in the firestore database